# Class vs enum class as an index type

Tags: c++, c++11, enum-class

[P0138R2 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0138r2.pdf) begins with<sup>1</sup>

> There is an incredibly useful technique for introducing a new integer type that is almost an exact copy, yet distinct type in modern C++11 programs: an 
>   `enum class` with an explicitly specified underlying type. Example:
>
> ```
> enum class Index : int { };    // Note: no enumerator.
> ```
>
> One can use `Index` as a new distinct integer type, it has no implicit conversion to anything (good!).

To convert `Index` to its underlying type it is useful to define

```
int operator*(Index index) {
    return static_cast<int>(index);
}
```

Another way to create `Index` type is to use old `class`:

```
class Index final {
public:
     explicit Index(int index = 0) : index_(index) { }

     int operator*() const {
         return index_;
     }

private:  
     int index_;
};
```

Both seem to be largely equivalent and can be used in the same way:

```
void bar(Index index) {
    std::cout << *index;
}

bar(Index{1});

int i = 1;
bar(Index{i});
```

Pro of `enum class`: the comparison operators are defined automatically, con of `enum class`: index value for the default constructed `enum class` can't be specified, it is always zero.

Are there other practical differences between these alternatives?

---

<sup>1</sup> I changed `uint32_t` to `int` to avoid `#include <cstdint>`.

Comment: Shouldn't your `operator*` return a reference?

Comment: @Rakete1111 (Edited) For the class version that could work, for the enum version that's impossible though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The first question has objective answers, assuming "practical" is objectively measurable (or defined widely).

Comment: I removed the second question.

Comment: `enum class` is the simpler solution, so I would go with it. Why is the default value so important?

Comment: @zett42, I do not claim that it is very important, but sometimes it may be useful to have the nonzero default value, e.g. `invalid = -1`. Probably, `enum class` is better in this case also: one has to be explicit and write `Index::invalid` instead of `Index{}`.

Comment: FWIW in C++20 we will have the spaceship operator which will make writing the comparisons a lot easier.

Comment: A con: for `enum class`, you cannot define a conversion nor assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative for strong types I use is a variation on [NamedTypes](https://github.com/joboccara/namedtype) by Jonathan Boccara. He nicely explains all of the details in multiple posts on his blog, see https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/

It's slightly more verbose in writing: `using Index = NamedType<int, struct IndexTag, Comparable, ImplicitlyConvertibleTo<int>>;`

When you construct this, you need to write something like `Index{0}`, though, the moment you use it as an index, it should automatically convert to the underlying type.

It has several advantages, including the ability to work on any type. The biggest disadvantage is that it's an external library you have to import instead of built-in functionality.