# Is it legal to declare a type as part of the template-argument for a type template-parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

The following snippet successfully compiles for all standard versions<sup>(1)</sup> for both Clang and GCC.

```
template<typename Tag>
struct Tagged {};

Tagged<struct Tag1> t1;
Tagged<struct Tag2> t2;
```

[[temp.arg.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.type#1) requires that

> A *template-argument* for a *template-parameter* which is a type shall be a *type-id*.

and [[temp.arg.type]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.type#2) contains the note

> [ *Note:* A template type argument may be an incomplete type ([basic.types]).  — *end note* ]

Thus, I would visit the grammar for a *template-argument* as well as a *type-id* to understand whether the former may also allow declaring an (incomplete) class type; in other words, if a *class-head* may be used as part of a *template-argument*; from [[class]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#nt:class-head):

> ```
> class-head:
>     class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt class-head-name class-virt-specifier_opt base-clause_opt
>     class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt base-clause_opt
>
> ...
>
> class-key:
>   class
>   struct
>   union
> ```

However, going down the rabbit hole for the grammar of [a *template-argument*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#nt:template-argument), [a *type-id*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.name#nt:type-id), [an *id-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.id#nt:id-expression) and eventually [an *identifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.name#nt:identifier) does not lead to, afaict, a grammar accepting a *class-head*.

I may be looking for the wrong grammar (*class-head*) to explain whether the snippet above is actually legal or not.

#### Question

- Is it legal to declare a type as part of the *template-argument* for a type *template-parameter*? If so, which part of the standard (say, C++17) governs this?

---

<sub>*(1) Note that if we place `Tagged<struct Tag1> t1;` e.g. within the scope of a function, the code is ill-formed in C++03, as *local types* were not allowed, back then, as template arguments for type template parameters.*</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>*(It seems the OP (myself) did not initially go deep enough down the type-id grammar rabbit hole)*</sub>

---

> Is it legal to declare a type as part of the template-argument for a type template-parameter?

Yes, this is legal.

> If so, which part of the standard (say, C++17) governs this?

A *class-key* and *identifier* grammar sequence, say `struct Tag1`, is [a valid *elaborated-type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier),

> ```
> elaborated-type-specifier:
>     class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt nested-name-specifier_opt identifier
>     ...
> ```

which in turn is [a valid *type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#nt:type-specifier),

> ```
> type-specifier:
>     elaborated-type-specifier
>     ...
> ```

which is turn is a valid single entry of [a *type-specifier-seq*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#nt:type-specifier-seq),

> ```
> type-specifier-seq:
>     type-specifier attribute-specifier-seq_opt
> ```

which in turn is [a valid *type-id*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.name#nt:type-id),

> ```
> type-id:
>     type-specifier-seq abstract-declarator_opt
>     ...
> ```

and as was noted in the OP, a *type-id*, as per [[temp.arg.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.type#1), is a valid *template-argument* for a type *template-parameter*;

> A *template-argument* for a *template-parameter* which is a type shall be a *type-id*.

Thus, the snippet

> ```
> template<typename Tag>
> struct Tagged {};
>
> Tagged<struct Tag1> t1;
> Tagged<struct Tag2> t2;
> ```

is well-formed.

Comment: I honestly don't think I knew that an only forward-declared struct (e.g `struct Tag;`) that had not been defined (e.g. `struct Tag{};`) was a valid template argument either. So I think that's what tripped me up here. What we end up with is just forward-declaring and using in a single breath, the template argument. Neat!

Comment: @underscore_d I knew we could use, as per [\[temp.arg.type\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.type#2), an incomplete type (say, just declared, not defined) as an argument for a type template parameter, but I had no idea that we could actually place the first (and single) _declaration_ of said type in the template argument itself. A neat trick for tagging, indeed!